# How to specify default Area to Html.BuildUrlFromExpression call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have problem like [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345293/how-to-specify-default-area-without-adding-area-to-every-actionlink)

All of my links look like this: htp//site/controller/action/id

I just added Area called **BackEnd**.

My Controller:

```
[ActionLinkArea("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now when I'm try to get some conroller URL using

```
@Html.ActionLink<HomeController >(c => c.Index(), "Home")
```

All works fine, and url is htp://site/HomeController/Index/

But when I use extension method from Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll

```
 @Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<HomeController>(c => c.Index())
```

I get URL htp://site/**BackEnd**/HomeController/Index/

How can I get URL without Area using BuildUrlFromExpression and why ActionLink works fine but 
BuildUrlFromExpression not?

Comment: I just have disassembled  Microsoft.Web.Mvc and found that this code VirtualPathData virtualPath = routeCollection.GetVirtualPath(context, routeValuesFromExpression); Where routeCollection abd context -we get from HtmlHelper, and routeValuesFromExpression - from expression return value with Area, but routeValuesFromExpression has normal value.

Comment: I have found answer: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7764 The method uses internally LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<T>().
The latter calls 
routeCollection.GetVirtualPath(context, routeValues) 
instead of 
routeCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(context, routeValues);
which causes invalid results when using areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Microsoft bug.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7764

The method uses internally LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression(). The latter calls routeCollection.GetVirtualPath(context, routeValues) instead of routeCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(context, routeValues); which causes invalid results when using areas.

I did it and method return correct URL

Answer (score 2):

I have better answer!

```
public static string Image<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<T>> action, int width, int height, string alt)
            where T : Controller
    {
        var expression = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        string actionMethodName = string.Empty;
        if (expression != null)
        {
            actionMethodName = expression.Method.Name;
        }
        string url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection).Action(actionMethodName, typeof(T).Name.Remove(typeof(T).Name.IndexOf("Controller"))).ToString();         
        //string url = LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<T>(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection, action);
        return string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" alt=\"{3}\" />", url, width, height, alt);
    }

<%=Html.Image<ClassController>(c => c.Index(), 120, 30, "Current time")%>
```