# MvcContrib strongly-typed BeginForm overload routes to portable area instead of consuming route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvccontrib, portable-areas

I am using MvcContrib 2.0.95.0 on an MVC2 web. We have created portable areas and are consuming them on a page.

On my viewpage that consumes a widget from my portable area, I have noticed that the BeginForm is routing my posts to my portable area.

```
using (Html.BeginForm<MyController>(f => f.SomeResult(null), FormMethod.Post){
}
```

This yields the following route. Note the Custom area in the route:

```
<form action="/Custom/My/SomeResult" class="observeform" id="SomeForm" method="post">
....

</form>
```

I placed the string overloaded BeginForm above it, for comparison sake:

```
using(this.Html.BeginForm("SomeResult", "My"))
{
```

My portable area does not possess this on controller, so I am confused as to why it would route here.

... and it produced the following *correct* route:

```
<form action="/My/SomeResult" method="post">
....
</form>
```

My portable area contains namespace constraints, whereas my consuming app's routing does 
not.

Without resorting to string overloads in my links and form creation, how can I prevent my portable area from polluting my consuming app's routing?

Answer (score 0):

Try decorating your controller with the `[ActionLinkArea]` attribute and specify an empty string to indicate that this controller belongs to the root site and not any area:

```
[Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ActionLinkArea("")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Now the `Html.BeginForm<MyController>` helper will generate the expected result.

Comment: Made this change, but it hasn't worked yet. I am digging further.

Comment: It appears that this is a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602786/how-to-specify-default-area-to-html-buildurlfromexpression-call).

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. I wasn't able to reproduce it because I was using a newer version of MVCContrib with ASP.NET MVC 3 where the `[ActionLinkArea]` attribute works fine.

Comment: Thanks for looking and the new attribute usage. I am still grokking Mvc Areas and see the utility in this.
My resolution for now will have to be to use the string overload. Meh.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, I took the following steps.

1. Retrieved the latest [Mvc2 Futures source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742#DownloadId=110347)
2. Altered the System.Web.Mvc reference to use the GAC library -- *not* the project reference.
3. Edited the following file: Microsoft.Web.Mvc.LinkBuilder, line 21:

   ```
   // changed this
   VirtualPathData vpd = routeCollection.GetVirtualPath(context, routeValues);

   // to this
   VirtualPathData vpd = routeCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(context, routeValues);
   ```
4. After I recompiled and deployed the dll to my project, I refactored my form code back to the strongly typed BuildForm() overload and it outputs the link correctly.